# Internal reference to an exercise/theorem (not to a section)

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to make a reference to an exercise/theorem which is numbered in my document with my own counters. Something like: as we saw in theorem 6.4.3, ...

My issue is that I don't want to use the section/chapter number but the number of my exercise/theorem. So the `\label` 
and `\ref` commands don't seem to do the job as far as I can see. I found this very interesting link looking down on here:

http://www.ryancreich.info/index.php?page=latex&subpage=rrthm

However, I couldn't adapt this - not good enough I'm afraid - and I precise that I'm not using the AMS-theorem environment because I defined my own.

Here is a short sample:

```
\documentclass{book}[11pt,a4paper]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{myCounter}
\setcounter{myCounter}{1}
\newcommand{\exercise}[1]{\textbf {Exercise \thechapter.\themyCounter }

    #1 \stepcounter{myCounter}
}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First chapter}

    \exercise{First exercise}

    \exercise{Second exercise}

    \exercise{Third exercise}

    Here I would like to make a reference to second exercise that would print ”Exercise 2.1" but would change whenever I add/remove an exercise/theorem before the given exercise.

    Something like : as we saw in "Exercise 2.1", the sum of integers from 1 to n is $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$

\end{document}
```

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don'tuse a dedicated package like `amsthm` or `ntheorem`?

Comment: Yes. My theorems/definitions/exercices are mostly inside tcolor boxes, so it's not compatible (I think)

Comment: Including these exercises?

Comment: Yeah it's a short sample, the document is much bigger and my results are in tcolorboxes. The exercices aren't in fact, but I mostly need references to theorems, properties or so. For instance to ask in an exercice to make the proof of properties 5.6.16.

Comment: That's not incompatible with theorem-like exercices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to go. However, I'd recoomend to use a theorem-like environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\newcounter{myCounter}
\counterwithin{myCounter}{chapter}
\setcounter{myCounter}{0}
\newcommand{\exercise}[1]{\refstepcounter{myCounter}\textbf {Exercice \themyCounter }
    #1
}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

    \chapter{First chapter}

    \exercise{First exercise\label{exo1}}

    \exercise{Second exercise\label{exo2}}

    \exercise{Third exercise\label{exo3}}

    Here I would like to make a reference to second exercice that would print ”Exercice 2.1" but would change whenever I add/remove an exercice/theorem before the given exercice.

    Something like : as we saw in "Exercice \ref{exo2}", the sum of integers from 1 to n is $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks to do the job. Can you please help me understand what `\counterwithin{myCounter}{chapter}`is doing in here ? It seems to make the references using this counter instead of chapter ? For doing this with the theorem-like environnment, my choice of doing this with my own environnment was to provide me a way to customize the look.

Comment: It resets myCounter at each new chapter, and prepends the chapter number (with a dot) to `\themyCounter`. I guess you could make it work with `cleveref`, which would make typing cross-references simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{book}[11pt,a4paper]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{deflist}

\newcounter{myCounter}[chapter]
\renewcommand\themyCounter{\thechapter.\arabic{myCounter}}
\newcommand\myCounterautorefname{\MyUppercasefork exercise}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifMyUppercase
\MyUppercasefalse
\DeclareRobustCommand\MyUppercasefork[1]{%
  \ifMyUppercase\expandafter\MakeUppercase\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\exercise}[1]{%
  \begin{deflist}{\textbf{Exercise 99.999}}%
  \refstepcounter{myCounter}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{%
    \myCounterautorefname\protect\space\themyCounter
  }%
  \item[{%
    \textbf{{\MyUppercasetrue\@currentlabelname}}%
   }]#1%
  \end{deflist}%
}%
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\enlargethispage{2cm}

\section*{References with clickable hyperlinks}

\verb|\ref{Ex2.1}|: \ref{Ex2.1}

\verb|\pageref{Ex2.1}|: \pageref{Ex2.1}

\subsection*{\texorpdfstring{\protect\texttt}{}%
             {\textbackslash MyUppercasefalse}:}
\MyUppercasefalse

\verb|\href{\string#myCounter.2.1}{A nice long link to \autoref*{Ex2.1}}|:\\
\href{\string#myCounter.2.1}{A nice long link to \autoref*{Ex2.1}}
\smallskip

\verb|\hyperref[Ex2.1]{A nice long link to \autoref*{Ex2.1}}|:\\
\hyperref[Ex2.1]{A nice long link to \autoref*{Ex2.1}}
\smallskip

\verb|\nameref{Ex2.1}|: \nameref{Ex2.1}

\verb|\autoref{Ex2.1}|: \autoref{Ex2.1}

\subsection*{\texorpdfstring{\protect\texttt}{}%
             {\textbackslash MyUppercasetrue}:}
\MyUppercasetrue

\verb|\nameref{Ex2.1}|: \nameref{Ex2.1}

\verb|\autoref{Ex2.1}|: \autoref{Ex2.1}

\MyUppercasefalse

\section*{References without clickable hyperlinks}

\verb|\ref*{Ex2.1}|: \ref*{Ex2.1}

\verb|\pageref*{Ex2.1}|: \pageref*{Ex2.1}

\subsection*{\texorpdfstring{\protect\texttt}{}%
             {\textbackslash MyUppercasefalse}:}
\MyUppercasefalse

\verb|\nameref*{Ex2.1}|: \nameref*{Ex2.1}

\verb|\autoref*{Ex2.1}|: \autoref*{Ex2.1}

\subsection*{\texorpdfstring{\protect\texttt}{}%
             {\textbackslash MyUppercasetrue}:}
\MyUppercasetrue

\verb|\nameref*{Ex2.1}|: \nameref*{Ex2.1}

\verb|\autoref*{Ex2.1}|: \autoref*{Ex2.1}

\MyUppercasefalse

\chapter{Second chapter}

\exercise{%
  \label{Ex2.1}First exercise of second chapter.
  First exercise of second chapter.
  First exercise of second chapter.
  First exercise of second chapter.
  First exercise of second chapter.
  First exercise of second chapter.
}

\exercise{Second exercise of second chapter.}

\exercise{Third exercise of second chapter.}

\exercise{Fourth exercise of second chapter.}

\exercise{Fifth exercise of second chapter.}

\exercise{Sixth exercise of second chapter.}

\exercise{Seventh exercise of second chapter.}

\exercise{Eighth exercise of second chapter.}

\exercise{Nineth exercise of second chapter.}

\exercise{Tenth exercise of second chapter.}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]